# Элемент формы не распознается в дополнительном .cpp файле.

Tags: c++builder

Здравствуйте.

Есть стандартный *Unit1.cpp* & *Unit1.h* и форма с полями ввода и *PaintBox'ом*.

Создаю *Another.cpp* & *Another.h* для описания в них своих функции, структур и тел функций.

Пишу в *Another.h* прототип функции `void Paint(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2)`
которая в *PaintBox'е* рисует прямоугольник по этим координатам *(х1,х2,у1,у2)*.

В *Another.cpp* прописываю тело функции:

```
void paint(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2)
{
    PaintBox1->Canvas->MoveTo(x1,y1)

    PaintBox1->Canvas->LineTo(x1,y2)
    ...

}
```

Но тут мне компилятор пишет, что *PaintBox1* это *Undefined Symbol*.
Я пробовал объявить в  *Another.h* элементы *Формы1*, тогда выскакивает такая ожидаемая *Multiple Declaration of TForm1*...

Ну собственно и вопрос, что делать дабы избавиться от ерора *Undefined Symbol*?)

P.S. Если описать прототип в  *Unit1.h* а тело в *Unit1.cpp* то *PaintBox1* все равно *Undefined Symbol*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько способов.

**Первый:** Раз идет обращение к визуальному компоненту, то эта процедура должна быть методом формы. То есть, paint должен быть объявлен в unit1 (правда имя не сильно подходящее у метода).

**Второй:** Добавить ещё один параметр

```
void paint(TPaintBox PaintBox1, int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2)
{
    PaintBox1->Canvas->MoveTo(x1,y1)
    PaintBox1->Canvas->LineTo(x1,y2)
    //...
}
```

Но только теперь придется вызывать метод так

```
 paint(PaintBox1, 0, 0, 100, 100);
```

**Третий:** в Another.h добавляем описание переменной `extern TPaintBox PaintBoxX;`, добавляем нужные include. В Another.cpp добавляем `TPaintBox PaintBoxX;` А в onCreate главной формы нужно добавить что то вида `PaintBoxX = PaintBox1;` А Вашу процедуру переписать так:

```
void paint(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2)
{
    PaintBoxX->Canvas->MoveTo(x1,y1)
    PaintBoxX->Canvas->LineTo(x1,y2)
    //...
}
```

Первый способ, как по мне, самый подходящий. Последний - для ценителей:).

Comment: Спасибо) Помогло)

Answer (score 1):

paint - это не метод класса TForm, поэтому он не видит элементы формы как поля класса TForm. 1) paint должен видеть переменную формы, которая и представляет собой главную форму (Form1 вроде называется по умолчанию?) 2) paint обращается к этой переменной и его поля Form1->PaintBox1->..

не держу Builder, проверить не могу

Comment: Компилирует но во время работы Access Violation at adress) Н овсе равно способ интересный спасибо)