# Передача переменной с cpp-файла в главную форму

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

Корни вопроса идут отсюда [Проблема с реализацией возможностей ofstream,istream в файле .cpp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/688129/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9-ofstream-istream-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5-cpp)
но сам вопрос уже совершенно другой

Сама проблема звучит таким образом
в `cpp`-файле есть динамический массив и мне нужно его содержимое вывести на график `Chart`, а `Chart` у меня на главной форме,следовательно...

Было сделано следующее

1)Объявил так же глобальную переменную в `TransEquForm`(главная форма)

```
    double** wht;
////-----идут куча разных методов-----/// 
    public:void drawdifnet(double** wht, int Nt)
        {
            chart2->Series["1"]->BorderWidth = 3;
            chart2->Series["2"]->BorderWidth = 3;
            chart2->Series["3"]->BorderWidth = 3;
            chart2->Series["4"]->BorderWidth = 3;
            chart2->Series["5"]->BorderWidth = 3;
            chart2->Series["6"]->BorderWidth = 3;
            chart2->Series["7"]->BorderWidth = 3;
            chart2->Series["8"]->BorderWidth = 3;
            chart2->Series["9"]->BorderWidth = 3;
            chart2->Series["10"]->BorderWidth = 3;
            chart2->Series["11"]->BorderWidth = 3;
            chart2->Series["12"]->BorderWidth = 3;
            for (int j = 1; j < Nt - 1; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < Nt - 1; i++)//Было Nx
                {
            chart2->Series["" + (j + 1).ToString()]->Points->AddXY(i, wht[j][i]);///–––Исключение-Ссылка не указывает на экземпляр объекта
                }
            }
        }
```

2-ой вариант это уже в файле `.cpp` где хранятся остальные процедуры.
Но в таком случае `chart2` нужно как-то передать,что у меня не получилось.(`TransEquForm` - это главная форма где всё расположено и где всё происходит)

```
void drawdifnet(TransEquForm chart2,double** wht, int Nt)
    {
        chart2->Series["1"]->BorderWidth = 3;
        chart2->Series["2"]->BorderWidth = 3;
        chart2->Series["3"]->BorderWidth = 3;
        chart2->Series["4"]->BorderWidth = 3;
        chart2->Series["5"]->BorderWidth = 3;
        chart2->Series["6"]->BorderWidth = 3;
        chart2->Series["7"]->BorderWidth = 3;
        chart2->Series["8"]->BorderWidth = 3;
        chart2->Series["9"]->BorderWidth = 3;
        chart2->Series["10"]->BorderWidth = 3;
        chart2->Series["11"]->BorderWidth = 3;
        chart2->Series["12"]->BorderWidth = 3;
        for (int j = 1; j < Nt - 1; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < Nt - 1; i++)//Было Nx
            {
                chart2->Series["" + (j + 1).ToString()]->Points->AddXY(i, wht[j][i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Вопросы:

1) Как можно передать переменную из `.cpp` файла в файл где форма?

2) Или мне проще будет загрузить данные с текстового файла в динамический массив и уже по ним строить график.

3) Или существуют возможность как-то передать из `Form`-ы компонент формы (`tChart` и другие) в `.cpp` файл и работать там напрямую?

Посмотрел эту тему [Элемент формы не распознается в дополнительном .cpp файле.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/66351/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-cpp-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5(%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) даже и Builder) но подсказки не помогли.

Comment: Объявить их `public`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov в случае с массивом wht генерируется исключение